# Active Directory ValidateCredentials breaks after Windows 10 November update

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-10

I have an existing project that uses the following for authenticating locally on dev machine

```
principalContext.ValidateCredentials("bondjames", "drno", ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

Please note this worked fine on Windows 10 up til this morning, am aware of previous issues with this.  I installed Windows 10 update 1511 and now it throws a FileNotFoundException.  I've [read of issues](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-november-update-issues-bugs) with the update but can't find anything on this.

If I provide an invalid password it simply returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar issue logged with [microsoft connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1904887/windows-10-insider-preview-build-10565) which suggested it to be missing registry entries in

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, specifically: `RegisteredOwner` and `RegisteredOrganization`.  I just put in my name and company respectively.  All tests pass now.

Note my issue would appear to have the same root cause as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33717673/system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-principalcontext-broken-after-windows) which I spotted had reference to same article.